# Why does using "=" result in no updated reference, while using "+=" updates the reference?

Tags: python, list

Why does using `=` result in no updated reference while using `+=` updates the reference?

```
x = [5,6,7]
y = []
y.append(x)
x += [8, 9]
```

```
t = [3,6]
v = []
v.append(t)
t = t + [4,5]
```

Comment: what do you mean by `updates the reference`? for list `+=` is similar to `.extend` method which mutates the original list. but `a = a+b` creates brand new list a with elements from `a` and `b`

Comment: Because `x += [8, 9]` is not short for `x = x + [8, 9]` here.

Answer (score 0):

With += you are updating the variable.
With `t = t + [4,5]` you are assigning a new variable.

So when you append something with x, and then update x, it will also update the appended variable. But when you assign another value to x, it won't